# How can I pass around a function with args, in red?

Tags: rebol, red

How can I pass a function as an argument in red?
Or would I not need that in red?

Using `does` I can define a function "with no arguments or local variables"

```
f: does [print 1] do f
>> 1
```

How can I make this work with (multiple) args? `does` is no the way, what is?

I want something like: (the following does NOT work):

```
; does NOT work
f: does-with-args [x][print x] do f 23
>> 1
```

In the last paragraph of this article http://blog.revolucent.net/2009/05/javascript-rebol.html the author says "allow functions to be passed as arguments" so I got excited, but it's also just using `does` :). But I learned it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I pass a function as an argument in red?

It doesn't seem this is the essence of your question, but you can pass a function as an argument in a couple of ways:

```
my-func: func [their-func [any-function!]][their-func "Stuff"]

my-func :print
my-func func [thing][probe uppercase thing]
```

> How can I make this work with (multiple) args?

There are two possibilities here. One is APPLY:

```
my-func: func [thing][print uppercase thing]
apply :my-func ["Foo"]
```

Another is to build up a block and DO it:

```
do collect [keep 'my-func keep "Bar"]
do collect [keep :my-func keep "Baz"] ; keeps the function itself
```

Comment: `apply` is now fully supported in Red, adding many new features. Use `? apply` from the console to see its specification. See the related [blog entry](https://www.red-lang.org/2023/06/dynamic-refinements-and-function.html) for more info.